# Phoenix app to sometimes run in isolation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two applications `parent` and `child` inside a phoenix umbrella project.

Inside of the router of `parent`, I have:

```
forward "/child", ChildWeb.Router
```

When I start `parent` (running `mix phx.server` from inside `apps/parent` app, or from the umbrella route), I would like it to bind to port `4000`, but for `child` to not start (not to bind to `4000`). All requests to the `child` router are something like: `/child/child_route`

**But**, When I start just `child` (running `mix phx.server` from `apps/child`). Would it be possible for that to bind to port `4000` and work independently. All `child` routes could be accessed by either `"/child/some_child_route"`

Would this be possible? It would be nice to not start `child` on a different port to the common main app port, as I would have to bind to `n` ports for each of the `n` apps in the umbrella project.

Comment: Only one `socket.listen` would succeed on the OS level, so you are to start your cowboys on different ports and have, say, `nginx` as a reverse proxy in front of them.